# How to Use External Node Movement Model on ONE Simulator

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, social-networking, simulator

I wanna ask how to run the external node movement  on default_settings.txt.

For instance I use the node movement model from http://crawdad.org/ (cambridge/haggle dataset) which contains of 5 files M1_day1.csv - M1_day5.csv).

what i have to write on default_settings.txt at Group.movementModel?

Kindly help your guidance and suggestion Sir.

I am very grateful for your help Sir.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely Yours,

DENI Y.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

Group.movementModel = ExternalMovement

ExternalMovement.file = ee/Haggle4-Cam-Imote.csv

Answer (score 0):

And how about we run 2 external movement model? Since it will override :
Group1.movementModel = ExternalMovement
ExternalMovement.file = xxx.csv

Group2.movementModel = ExternalMovement
ExternalMovement.file = yyy.csv

Notice that ExternalMovement.file is overrided by previous line